# Gstreamer SDK with hardware decoder enabling for iOS8

Tags: ios8, video-streaming, gstreamer, hardware-acceleration

I was looking for a way to use hardware decoder in iOS8 in the  gstreamer pipeline.

**I have followed below approach:**

1) Downloaded the package from
     http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/ios/1.4.3/   and installed in the mac machine [ 10.9.4]

2) I have managed to compile sample code in Xcode, and i was using the below pipeline components for decoding RTP packets in the steaming channel.

```
udpsrc port=5000 ! application/x-rtp, clock-rate=90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, payload=96  ! rtph264depay ! vtdec! autovideosink sync=true
```

3) Unfortunately it could not find vtdec or  vtdec_h264 component.

4) To check if hardware decoder plugin inside the library, xplored little bit on the installaed Package:

**The below is the output of otool  over Gstreamer Mach-O universal binary with 3 architectures.**

```
GStreamer(libgstapplemedia_a_armv7_-libgstapplemedia_la-corevideobuffer.o) (architecture armv7):
GStreamer(libgstapplemedia_a_armv7_-libgstapplemedia_la-atdec.o) (architecture armv7):
GStreamer(libgstapplemedia_a_armv7_-libgstapplemedia_la-plugin.o) (architecture armv7):
GStreamer(libgstapplemedia_a_armv7_-libgstapplemedia_la-vtutil.o) (architecture armv7):
GStreamer(libgstapplemedia_a_armv7_-libgstapplemedia_la-coremediabuffer.o) (architecture armv7):
GStreamer(libgstapplemedia_a_armv7_-libgstapplemedia_la-dynapi.o) (architecture armv7):
GStreamer(libgstapplemedia_a_armv7_-libgstapplemedia_la-vtapi.o) (architecture armv7):
GStreamer(libgstapplemedia_a_armv7_-libgstapplemedia_la-iosassetsrc.o) (architecture armv7):
GStreamer(libgstapplemedia_a_armv7_-libgstapplemedia_la-avfvideosrc.o) (architecture armv7):
GStreamer(libgstapplemedia_a_armv7_-libgstapplemedia_la-avfassetsrc.o) (architecture armv7):
GStreamer(libgstapplemedia_a_armv7_-libgstapplemedia_la-coremediactx.o) (architecture armv7):
```

**Finding:**

1)  The above does not entail, libgstapplemedia_la-vtdec.o

2)  The  Makefile.am of gst-plugins-bad-1.4.3/sys/applemedia has following code.

```
if HAVE_VIDEOTOOLBOX
      libgstapplemedia_la_SOURCES +=  vtenc.c  vtdec.c
      libgstapplemedia_la_LDFLAGS += -Wl,-framework -Wl,VideoToolbox
endif
```

**QUESTION:**

1) Having said the above understanding is correct [ please correct me if i am wrong],
   where can i get the iOS GStreamer SDK library with hardware decoding functions, which
   can be used in iOS8.

2) If not, Do we have to build GStreamer SDK on our own with the help of Cerbero build system?

What other quirk i need to be aware of?

Answer (score 4):

You will have to wait for the 1.4.4 release, or build yourself with the cerbero build system. Either from the 1.4 or master branch. You can get it here: http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/cerbero/

For building yourself you will need the iOS8 SDK, otherwise the hardware decoders/encoders are not built. Also in your application you'll have to add "-weak-framework VideoToolbox" to your linker flags next to the other frameworks.

In 1.4.3 and before, vtdec/vtenc was only available for OSX.